# Find next highest and next lowest number in a sequence

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

How to find the lowest and highest value couples in a sequence of number? I want to save the low/high values of a line graph.

[image: graph]

Can you help me with a piece of pseudo code so people can implement the answer in their favorite prog language.

I will be using this to generate a line graph with D3.js. If anybody knows how to do this with D3 I would be more than happy to know about it.

Data Sample:
[**20**, 10, 11, **5**, 15, **25**, 10, **5**, 15, 17, **26**, 15, **7**]

```
Desired Result:
array[0][high] = 20
array[0][low] = 5
array[1][high] = 25
array[1][low] = 5
array[2][high] = 26
array[2][low] = 7
```

This is what I have so far (in Javascript). Do you guys see anyway we can optimize this piece of code?

```
// data sample
var data_sample = Array(5, 15, 20, 15, 6, 11, 21, 14, 9, 4, 15, 20, 15, 1, 10, 20, 4);

// algo
var low = high = k = 0;
var log = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data_sample.length; i++) {

    var current = data_sample[i];
    var m = i+1;
    var next = data_sample[m];

    if (typeof next == 'undefined') {
        break;
    }

    if (current < next) {
        if (low === 0) {
            low = current;
        } else if (current < low) {
            low = current;
        }
    } else if (current > next && low !== 0) {
        if (high === 0) {
            high = current;
        } else if (current > high) {
            high = current;
        }
    }

    if (low > 0 && high > 0){
        log[k] = [];
        log[k]['low'] = low;
        log[k]['high'] = high;
        k++
        low = high = 0;
    }

};
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is you array initialized like that or it's just a typo?  It's not multidimensional.

Comment: It is a 2 dimensional array. It is just to illustrate that the resulting array would contain the first high/low number of the sequence in the 0 dimension and the second low/high value in the 1 dim and so on.

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it because it was dependent on choosing 3 results, is that up to you to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = [20, 10, 11, 5, 15, 25, 10, 6, 15, 17, 26, 15, 7],
    sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});

var array = [];

sorted.forEach(function(d,i){
   var s = []; 
   s.push(sorted[i], sorted[(sorted.length-1) - i]);
   array.push(s);
});

console.log(array);
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t986cjxc/)

Comment: Thx Johnroe, I cannot use sort since these are the value of a line graph. With your sequence, the final array should be [[20,5],[25,6], [26,7]]

Comment: The result of this is not what you wanted.  It' just sorted by pair, `[first, last],[second, last -1] ....`

Answer (score 0):

The missing part of your code is how to store as array or object.

In your last `if condition` before you end the `for loop` you need to initialize `log[k]` as an object then add the property `low` and `high` like this

```
 if (low > 0 && high > 0){
      log[k] = {};
      log[k].low = low;
      log[k].high = high;
      k++
      low = high = 0;
 }
```

Doing so will result is

```
array[0]{high: 20, low: 5}
array[1]{high: 25,low: 6}
```

If you want it to be an multidimensional array you do it like this:
Initialize `log[k]` as ab empty array.

```
 if (low > 0 && high > 0){
      log[k] = [];
      log[k]['low'] = low;
      log[k]['high'] = high;
      k++
      low = high = 0;
 }
```

And the result

```
array[0]['high'] = 20
array[0]['low'] = 5
array[1]['high'] = 25
array[1]['low'] = 6
```

Comment: Good point andrex. It makes the code cleaner. Since I will be processing many thousands of records with this function. Do you see anyway we can optimize the code? Like faster execution and/or less memory usage? Thank you